# Out of bag observation in randomForest R-Package

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, regression, random-forest

I need to find the object in randomForest that has the out-of-bag data. The out-of-bag error rate can be found but the observations on which this error is based are not given. How to find this object?

Comment: Have you tried `str`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. In general `randomForest` will create many out-of-bag samples in the course of the algorithm, not one. So there is not one out-of-bag observation set to begin with.

Search through http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf to see mentions of how out-of-bag is used.

Comment: Yes randomForest will create many out-of-bag samples but if I keep number of trees equal to one then then there should be only one out-of-bag sample. Is it still not possible?

Comment: It depends on the way RF is implemented. The way you're imagining, yes, but for the reason I gave, you will probably not find an API for this.